# Why is my Cordova Geolocation so inaccurate

Tags: angularjs, cordova, geolocation, ionic-framework

I'm working on a Track & Share Module for Pilots, the app is build with AngularJS within Ionic and Cordova framework. I'm currently developting and testing for android only.

The case:
There are four buttons, first checks if gps is enabled, second starts the tracking, third stops the tracking, fourth send the trackdata to the web-API if internet connection is stable. I can't guarantee 100% connectivity up in the air, so I can't send the trackdata on every tracked waypoint direct to the api - I have to store it until the aircraft is on the ground again.

The problem:
The tracked waypoints are (1) temporally/timely highly variable (I can't get any pattern on my test-tracks) and (2) the tracked altitude/heading/speed data isn't recorded on some trackpoints.

My flown test-route is about 40 minutes. I'm tracking every 60 seconds. So I must get at least minimum 35-40 trackpoints. But: I just get between 9 and 15 trackpoints on that route..

Trackpoints:

1442050712218|51.4514495|6.8892898|null|null|null;  12.9.2015 11:38:32
1442051327924|51.5183441|6.8183962|null|null|null;  12.9.2015 11:48:48
1442051511529|51.8569473|6.8611548|null|null|null;  12.9.2015 11:51:52
1442051732401|51.9828794|6.9063169|null|null|null;  12.9.2015 11:55:32
1442051912503|52.0233909|6.9596959|1300|64|52.25;   12.9.2015 11:58:33
1442052014828|52.0400627|7.0322238|1332|75|51.25;   12.9.2015 12:00:15
1442052517583|52.1472176|7.3813409|1307|70|51.5;    12.9.2015 12:08:38
1442052746410|52.1859082|7.5392811|1217|68|53;      12.9.2015 12:12:26
1442053119338|52.224271|7.874347|null|null|null;    12.9.2015 12:18:39
1442053401324|52.2677044|7.9679879|null|null|null;  12.9.2015 12:23:21

[image: Trackpoints in my web-view]

```
.service('TrackingFunctions', ['$interval', '$rootScope', '$localstorage', function($interval, $rootScope, $localstorage) {

    // Erstellt einmalige "global" Referenz, dass immer die selbe Instanz angesprochen wird
    var tracker;

        this.doTracking = function(execTracking){
            if(!execTracking){ // if no tracker start new
                $localstorage.TRACKDATA = [];

                return $interval(function(){
                    $localstorage.isTrackerActive = true;
                    var geo_options = {
                        enableHighAccuracy: true,
                        maximumAge: 30000,
                        timeout: 20000
                    };
                    function geo_success(position) {
                        console.log(position);

                        var tsmp = position.timestamp;
                        var lat = position.coords.latitude;
                        var lng = position.coords.longitude;
                        var alt = position.coords.altitude;
                        var hdg = position.coords.heading;
                        var spd = position.coords.speed;

                        var ARRAYDATA = tsmp + "|" + lat + "|" + lng + "|" + alt + "|" +hdg + "|" + spd + ";";

                        $localstorage.TRACKDATA.push(ARRAYDATA);

                    }
                    function geo_error() {
                        //$scope.alt = "Fehler " + error.message + ' Error Code: ' + error.code;
                    }
                    var wpid = navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(geo_success, geo_error, geo_options);

                },60000); // getrackt wird alle 60 Sekunden

            } else { // if tracker cancel
                $interval.cancel(execTracking);
                console.log("tracker deaktiviert!");
            }
        };
}])
```

How can I fix that the app tracks every 60 seconds and the missing data will be recorded, too? The function is crucial fot the app and webservice for flight-training for solo-flights of the student pilot.

Thank you.

Comment: Are you getting any errors? You don't seem to log the errors. Log the errors inside the error callback and share the output.

Answer (score 0):

Just an idea:

The timeout is not a accurate task, that means, timeout is working when all other tasks are done. It's more like: You should run every 60 seconds.

In your case, I would save the position continuous and would write a «clock/timer», called every second. In your script you calculate the exact starttime, e.g.: 09:27:16. After starttime + x * 60 seconds you trigger in your clock the final saving of the position.

If this is not working, I would test it by using a Web Worker.